# Yii2 - Calling model functions on entire activeRecords?

Tags: php, activerecord, model, yii2

**What I am trying to do**

I want to query a specific set of records using active model like so

```
$jobModel = Jobs::find()->select('JOB_CODE')->distinct()->where(['DEPT_ID'=>$dept_id])->all();
```

Then I want to assign a flag attribute to the records in this activerecord based on whether they appear in a relationship table

**What I have tried**

So in my job model, I have declared a new attribute `inAccount`. Then I added this function in the job model that sets the `inAccount` flag to -1 or 0 based on whether a record is found in the relationship table with the specified `account_id`

```
public function assignInAccount($account_id){
    if(JobCodeAccounts::find()->where(['JOB_CODE'=>$this->JOB_CODE])->andWhere(['ACCOUNT_ID'=>$account_id])->one() == null){
        $this->inAccount=0;
    }
    else{
        $this->inAccount = -1;
    }
}
```

What I have been doing is assigning each value individually using foreach like so

```
foreach($jobModel as $job){
    $job->assignInAccount($account_id);
}
```

However, this is obviously very slow because if I have a large number of records in `$jobModel`, and each one makes a db query in `assignInAccount()` this could obviously take some time if the db is slow.

**What I am looking for**

I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this, so that I can assign `inAccount` to all job records at once. I considered using `afterFind()` but I don't think this would work as I need to specify a specific parameter. I am wondering if there is a way I can pass in an entire model (or at least array of models/model-attributes and then do all the assignations running only a single query.

I should mention that I do need to end up with the original `$jobModel` activerecord as well

Comment: Could you explain why you are adding this flag  ??

Comment: I am using a yii widget that creates a dual list given an activerecord and a flag attribute (`inAccount` in this case), and the flag attribute will determine which side of the dual list to place the model

Comment: you could use a select join  for get the values  that match or not with a query only ..

Comment: Thanks! Does seem to be quite a bit faster now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to scaisEdge's answer I was able to come up with an alternative solution, first finding the array of jobs that need to be flagged like so:

```
    $inAccountJobs = array_column(Yii::$app->db->createCommand('Select * from job_code_accounts where ACCOUNT_ID = :account_id')
        ->bindValues([':account_id' => $account_id])->queryAll(), 'JOB_CODE');
```

and then checking each job record to see if it appears in this array like so

```
    foreach($jobModel as $job){
        if(in_array($job->JOB_CODE, $inAccountJobs))
            $job->inAccount = -1;
        else
            $job->inAccount = 0;
    }
```

Does seem to be noticeably faster as it requires only a single query.

Comment: the use of direct command is always faster than activeRecord (ORM)  ..  but you could improve the query using a left join with the matchinh table where you have match you can assign a value where not you can assign another  in one query only